# Strange text capturing in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, text-capture

Looks like I pressed some key combination or something. 
I cannot capture code as usual. Idea captures not the whole method but text according to the level of the cursor. 
Does anyone know how to turn on/off this feature?
I use ultimate version 2017.1

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've probably enabled `Column selection mode`, which on Windows has as default shortcut: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>INSERT</kbd>.

[image: keymap settings]

You can also *temporarily* enable this selection mode, by holding down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key, then clicking and dragging with the mouse over the block of text you want to select, like this:

[image: column mode selection]

Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html) because there are a few other useful features you can take advantage of.